# Proving this definition of a morphism of schemes is continuous

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am reading a book called *Toric Varieties* by Cox et. al, where I came across this definition of a morphism. Let $U_i \subseteq V_i$ be Zariski open sets of affine varieties for $i=1,2$. A mapping $\Phi:U_1 \rightarrow U_2$ is morphism if $\phi \rightarrow \phi \circ \Phi$ defines a map from $\phi^*:\mathcal{O}_{V_2}(U_2) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{V_1}(U_1)$, where $\mathcal{O}_{V_i}(U_i)$ is the set of all regular functions from $U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Now I should mention the definition of regular function also.

Consider $V=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ be an affine variety. Let $f \in R$ be a polynomial function on $R$, then $V_f=V\setminus V(f)$ is a Zariski open set. Now, we know that these are affine open sets which form basis for Zariski topology in $V$. Now, we will call a function $U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a regular function, if for every $p \in U$, there exists $f_p \in R$ such that $p \in V_{f_p} \subseteq U$ and $\phi|_{V_{f_p}}\in R_{f_p}$. So essentially, for every $p$, $\phi(p)=a_p/f_p^{n_p}$ with $f_p(p) \neq 0$ and $n_p \geq 0.$

I don't understand how a morphism is a continuous function in the Zariski Topology.

I will be grateful if you can help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $V_1$ and $V_2$ affine varieties, to show a morphism $\Phi: V_1\to V_2$ is continuous.

Enough to show that for $D(f)\subset V_2$ (where $D(f)=V_2-V(f)$ for $f$ a polynomial function on $V_2$), $\Phi^{-1}(D(f))$ is open in $V_1$.

Now $\phi^*: \mathcal{O}(V_2)\to \mathcal{O}(V_1)$ takes regular functions on $V_2$ to $V_1.$ Let $g:=\phi^*(f)$ regular function on $V_1$. Check $D(g)=\Phi^{-1}(D(f))$.

Now to see **in general:** for $V_1$ and $V_2$ (not necessarily affine) varieties, a morphism $\Phi: V_1\to V_2$ is continuous.

So we want to see that for any open subset $U_2\subset V_2$, $\Phi^{-1}(U_2)$ is open in $V_1$.

Cover $U_2$ by basic open sets $D(f_i)$'s. Now
$$\Phi^{-1}(U_2)=\bigcup_{i}\Phi^{-1}(D(f_i)) .$$

So
$$\Phi^{-1}(U_2)=\bigcup_{i}D(\phi^*(f_i)).$$

Hence $\Phi^{-1}(U_2)$ is open in $V_1$.

Comment: I get this part, but what about when the open set is written as finite union of affine open subset. Then, can we show that restriction of a morphism to an affine open subset is indeed a morphism?

Comment: @user631697 So you are asking how to show from this that a general morphism $\phi: V_1\to V_2$ of (not necessarily affine) varieties is continuous?

Comment: Yes precisely that's what I am asking. For example, when two open sets are not not affine, I.e, it is written as union of affine open sets $U_i$, then how can we show this morphism is indeed continuous?

Comment: @user631697 Added the explanation.